# Unresolved external symbol errors without #pragma comment lib command

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker, c++-cli

I added a project to my VS2008 solution and set a dependency to this newly added project in my startup project via the project settings window. The problem was that I had `unresolved external symbol` errors all over the place, but once I wrote the line `#pragma comment (lib, "path_to/my_lib.lib")` inside the file using the functions of my library, everything worked just fine. Specifically, I added that line right after my include

```
#include "path_to/my_lib.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "path_to/my_lib.lib")
```

I read that to set the dependencies in the project settings window and writing the line `#pragma comment (lib, "path_to/my_lib.lib")` was the same thing. Why did I have all the unresolved external symbol errors without that specific line written in the code? Is it because it's looking for this dependency in a different folder given in the VC++ Directories in the VS2008 options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question.

*"...was the same thing..."* No, it is not the same thing.

***Project Dependencies*** If your selected project, P0, depends on project DLL1 but does not depend on project DLL3, the IDE is updating (buidling) DLL1 before P0. See the first picture, below.

***Linker Dependencies (link to a library)*** Use `#pragam comment(lib...` or go to project's settings to select the libraries. The libraries do not necessary belong to your solution. See the second picture, below.

Wrong project dependencies may generate link errors if, for instance:

- the library is part of your solution
- you modified the library's interface (changed a function signature, for instance)
- you modify the project to fit the new interface (call the function with its new signature)
- the dependencies of your project are **not set to first build (update) the library project**; therefore it tries to link to the old library (old function signature)

[image]
[image]