# 'byte' : ambiguous symbol error when using of Crypto++ and Windows SDK

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, crypto++, cbc-mode

In *Visual Studio 2012*, I'm trying to encrypt a file with Crypto++ library with `AES` encryption and `CBC` mode as following :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "aes.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "files.h"
#include <Shlwapi.h>

using namespace CryptoPP;

INT main(INT argc, CHAR *argv[])
{
    CHAR szKey[16] = {0};
    CHAR szInitVector[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH] = {0};

    StrCpyA(szKey, "qqwweeff88lliioo");
    StrCpyA(szInitVector, "eerrttooppkkllhh");

    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryptor((byte*)szKey, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, (byte*)szInitVector);
    FileSource fs("in.txt", true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new FileSink("out.aes")));

    return 0;
}
```

In `Qt` it does work!, But here I wondered why got the following `error` :

```
error C2872: 'byte' : ambiguous symbol
could be 'c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\rpcndr.h(164) : unsigned char byte'
or 'z:\cryptography\app_aesencryption\aes headers\config.h(237) : CryptoPP::byte'
```

Due to prevent of `ambiguous symbol` error, even I cast bellow statement with `CryptoPP::byte*` :

```
CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryptor((CryptoPP::byte*)szKey, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, (CryptoPP::byte*)szInitVector);
```

I didn't get any error for `'byte' : ambiguous symbol`, But It give me many `errors` as :

```
error LNK 2038
```

By the way, I linked `.lib` file of Crypto++, So I think this error is Unlikely for this.
Is last `error` related to `CryptoPP::byte*`? Is there any solution?

Comment: Remove `using namespace CryptoPP;`  as this statement brings `CryptoPP::byte` into the global namespace and `rpcndr.h` has already typedef'd `unsigned char` as  `byte`

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried with `CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<AES>` namespace directly. but it does not work.

Comment: _"...does not work..."_ is not a problem report I can help you with.

Comment: @RichardCritten let me try it...

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Cast it to CryptoPP::byte*.

Comment: @ZDF it give me a lot of `error LNK 2038` list when i try  this --> `CryptoPP::byte*`

Comment: So, it fixes the error. Go to linker options and add the CryptoPP library.

Comment: @ZDF I added library dependencies before!

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi **Rebuild all**. Rebuld also any used *.lib or *.obj from `z:\cryptography\`.

Comment: [`using namespace whatever` is a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714). The larger the namespace the more chance you'll get problem

Comment: Check that the library you're trying to link is added to your options.

Comment: @ZDF which options? sorry i didn't get you

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2038](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2038)

Comment: Linker dependencies. Go to Project Properties | Linker | Input (if I correctly remember the commands). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671578/1983409).

Comment: @ZDF it was correct

Comment: You have incopatible settings for main app and cryptolib. For example different **Project->Properties->General->Platform Toolset**. Please show full error message.

Comment: If you don't like to write `CryptoPP::<Everything>`, you can replace `using namespace CryptoPP` with `namespace crp = CryptoPP;` for instance. You can now use `crp::` in place of `CryptoPP::`, e. g. `crp::byte`. No ambiguities anymore but still less typing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [byte and ambiguous symbol due to using declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45125957/608639) Also see [Windows and "error C2872: 'byte' : ambiguous symbol"](http://crypto-users.996303.n3.nabble.com/Windows-and-quot-error-C2872-byte-ambiguous-symbol-quot-td7549.html) on the Crypto++ mailing list.

Comment: If you dont want to change the casts, you could do `using byte = CryptoPP::byte;`

Comment: perfect example of why 'using namespace xxx' is a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem solved with changing `byte*` to `CryptoPP::byte*` :

```
CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryptor((CryptoPP::byte*)szKey, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, (CryptoPP::byte*)szInitVector);
```

But to solving the second problem (`error LNK 2038`) :

This is related to `link error`, Every body that using of `crypto++` in *Visual Studio* may have this problem.

First I was download library from bellow link for *visual studio* in which containt `.sln` (VS Solution) :

- > https://www.cryptopp.com/#download
- I build the library via <kbd>Batch Build</kbd> as `cryptlib` project in both state (`Debug|Win32` and `Release|Win32`)
- Because I used of `Debug` mode, I linked `cryptlib.lib` in `cryptopp700\Win32\Output\Debug` in dependencies section.
- Also add dependencies for header files...

But I forgot something in project properties :

Finally, I set Runtime Library option to <kbd>Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)</kbd>

This option is in :

- <kbd>Project Properties</kbd>
- <kbd>Configuration Properties</kbd>
- <kbd>C/C++</kbd>
- <kbd>Code Generation</kbd>
- <kbd>Runtime Library</kbd>

Comment: Yes CRT configuration has to be compatible between all object modules. Repeat this also for Release configuration.

Comment: @SHR yes my problem was also CRT configuration

Comment: *"Finally, I set Runtime Library option to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)..."* - Also see [Visual Studio | Runtime Linking](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_studio#Runtime_Linking) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 2):

> 'byte' : ambiguous symbol error when using of Crypto++

We had to move `byte` from global namespace to `CryptoPP` namespace due to C++17 and `std::byte`. The change occurred at [Commit 00f9818b5d8e](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/00f9818b5d8e), which was part of the Crypto++ 6.0 release.

Crypto++ used to put `byte` in the global namespace for compatibility with Microsoft SDKs. Without the global byte then you would encounter *`'byte' : ambiguous symbol error`* again.

The error you are seeing is because you used `using namespace CryptoPP;` ***and*** the Microsoft kits still put a `byte` in the global namespace. The error did not surface under Qt because Qt does not put a byte in the global namespace.

There are several work-arounds discussed at [`std::byte`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Std::byte) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Incidentally, Microsoft kit code will break when it encounters a C++17 compiler and `std::byte` because of Microsoft's global `byte`. You will encounter the same error when using the Windows kits. Ironically, Microsoft employees authored C++ `std::byte`. Also see [PR0298R0, A byte type definition](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0298r0.pdf).

Comment: "Microsoft kits still put a byte in the global namespace" ... the way it's done in platform headers makes it very unlikely that they even can stop doing that. Doesn't look like it's going to change. Instead of using byte cryptopp should just use uint8_t

Comment: @Pavel - Crypto++ is no longer part of the problem since its byte is now scoped. The problem is solely Microsoft and their headers now. Hindsight being 20/20 Crypto++ should have not attempted to be compatible with Microsoft SDK headers. But the decision was made in 1995 and it was hard to change until the C++17 breaks came.

Comment: ms headers don't care about c++ (why should they?) they, they are C after all. They have that byte type in many structures, and it's reasonable to typedef it as an unsigned char. I wouldn't say that "the problem is solely Microsoft and their headers". They might as well say the problem is in c++ or whatever. Note, I don't deal with crypto and never had that byte problem myself, just tried to look how they define it in headers and if there was a way to prevent that typedef.

Comment: @Pavel - Microsoft blaming C++ or C++ blaming Microsoft works for me. I don't have a dog in that fight. I'm fine with it as long as the problem is not with Crypto++.

Comment: It's not in cryptopp also. However, since there was std::byte added, it makes sense to use std::byte, or to change internal code to use uint8_t if it doesn't match semantics of std::byte (to avoid future confusion). Also, just curious, if cryptopp also typedefed it as unsigned char, then there wouldn't be any problem IMO

Comment: @Pavel - `uint8_t` typedef is not a good choice for Crypto++. We support too many compilers and platforms. Some of the time we will be able to use `<stdint.h>` and `uint8_t`; and other times `<stdint.h>` will be missing and we will have to provide a `typedef`. Part of the appeal of `byte`, `word16`, `word32` and friends was avoiding that problem (until C++17 and the byte problem arrived). And I cringe when thinking about the problems of removing the symbol after 28 years. Users will want to tar and feather us.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is not directly relating to Crypto++ & Windows SDK, but I know I found this while trying to figure out the same error when using the Nodejs addon library called Nan instead.  I'm putting this answer here because it's in an accessible place for others who might run into similar issues to me.

I hadn't had too many issues compiling the project for a while but then ran into the same error as mentioned above.  I wasn't using a `byte` symbol anywhere.  There were dozens of errors pointing to libraries in the Windows SDK which also was conflicting with the `cstddef` header as the error addresses.

What I was able to do to fix the problem was rearranging the headers so that the Nan-related content (and any of my own header files that references it) was on top, above even the other standard C/C++ libraries.  After that was done, the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

The decision is simpliest. Delete from your code 'using namespace std' and use namespace std:: before every operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#define _HAS_STD_BYTE 0